# Confusing example of active and passive

Tags: grammar, active-voice, active-vs-passive

There is asentence which has confused me a lot.

> *Margarine category was recorded least.*
>
> *Least recorded category was Margarine.*

Which sentence is active and which is passive. I am facing difficulty in finding the mistake.

Comment: Minor grammar comment: this is a superlative (_least_) and so the definite article is required: _The margarine category was recorded least_ and _The least recorded category was Margarine_. Both are correct, incidentally. The first sentence is actually a passive (_be_ + Past Participle as main verb, no agent, patient promoted to subject), but the second one is not. It's just an equational sentence like _The winner was Mat_. The subject contains an complex adjective (_least-recorded_) that's formed from a past participle; but that doesn't make the sentence passive.

Comment: @John Lawler..no agent and patient promoted to subject. What are these two terms? Patient? In my first sentence which is subject and which one is object.

Comment: There is no object because the sentence is passive and passives don't have objects. "Agent" means the one who does something; "patient" means the one things are done to. In _They recorded the Margarine category, they_ is the agent and _the Margarine category_ is the patient. These are semantic relations, not grammatical ones like "subject" and "object". Passive doesn't change the semantic relations, just the grammatical ones. It changes the patient NP (normally the object) to subject, and usually omits the agent NP (because it's irrelevant or already known).

Comment: What my teacher has taught me that we can change any active to passive and the basic rule is to change the place of subject with object. So how come a passive sentence can be used without an object . Its really confusing.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. Only **transitive** clauses can be passivized. There must be a subject NP and an object NP. Many clauses are intransitive, and they can't be passivized.

Comment: Ok thanks sir...So can there be any active version of my first passive sentence?

Comment: _They recorded the Margarine category (the) least_. The second _the_ is optional. The agent subject (_they_) is not present in the passive, so we can't tell what it was in reality; indefinite _they_ is just a place-holder here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a native UK English speaker and I have only a tentative idea, to me this is tricky.

My suggestion is reduce the two examples to the bare minimum:

> X was recorded

we don't know by whom, call him Dave

> X was recorded by Dave

That's passive, active would be

> Dave recorded X

So your first sentence is passive. The second sentence "least recorded" is just an adjective describing the catgory, the actual verb is "was", reducing it:

> The category was Margerine

That is like

> Dave was tall

This is not passive. [See this article](https://m.wikihow.com/Understand-the-Difference-Between-Passive-and-Active-Sentences) for further discussion, under heading (3) in that article we have:

> Understand the verb in a passive sentence. In a passive sentence,
>   something happens to the subject. The verb is the action that happens.
>   It begins with a "to be" verb (for example, "is," "was," "were," "has
>   been," "will have been"), then a verb in a past tense.

In your example the "recorded" is not linked to the "was".